# Yudhistira's charity while in forest

Tags: mahabharata, yudhisthira

In the Tirthyatra parva of Vana parva, there are repeated texts (example [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03118.htm)) saying Yudhistira have given away gems, cows and jewels to Brahmanas.
...

> the king observed various fasts, and gave away large quantities of gems
> ...

> distributed riches to the leaders of the twice-born class

....

> Then he gave away thousands of cows at those holy spots

As Yudhistira was in forest and no longer the king, from where was he getting the wealth?

He was blessed with Akshaya Patra to feed the brahmanas. Was that the source of wealth as well? Or any other references I missed?

Comment: Yes on reaching forest he got surya mantra upedsha from  sowmya Archaya. offical. prohit of pandavas, he started the japa..early in the morning and withing noon he got surya deva darshan and akshya patra.. so he gave all that he got from akshya to brahmanas who are patranized in indrasprastha they were also in the forest along with attendants.. he was able todo this daily live happily in forest after 7 years drupadi chides yuddhistra for not waging war along with bheema..